# Function parameter type-setting returning SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, types, arguments

I have a python script that contains a type declaration of function arguments as following:

```
def dump_var(v: Variable, name: str = None):
```

To my knowledge, this is a valid syntax that sets a type of input parameters to the function, but it returns a

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What may be wrong?

Comment: Python 2.7 doesn't support type hints, so that is invalid syntax.

Comment: Python 2.7 does not support type hints.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SyntaxError is because Python 2.7 doesn't support type hints. You may either use **Python 3.5+** or use type hints for Python 2.7 **in comments** as [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code) suggests:

> ### Suggested syntax for Python 2.7 and straddling code
>
> Some tools may want to support type annotations in code that must be compatible with Python 2.7. For this purpose this PEP has a suggested (but not mandatory) extension where function annotations are placed in a `# type:` comment. Such a comment must be placed immediately following the function header (before the docstring). An example: the following Python 3 code:
>
> ```
> def embezzle(self, account: str, funds: int = 1000000, *fake_receipts: str) -> None:
>     """Embezzle funds from account using fake receipts."""
>     <code goes here>
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the following:
>
> ```
> def embezzle(self, account, funds=1000000, *fake_receipts):
>     # type: (str, int, *str) -> None
>     """Embezzle funds from account using fake receipts."""
>     <code goes here>
> ```